# How can retorfit2 get this json correct?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

My json string is produced as below:

```
    header('Content-type:text/json');
    if (mysql_num_rows ( $result ) != 0) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $jobj=new stdclass();
        foreach($row as $key=>$value){
            $jobj->$key=$value;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($jobj,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

In browser, the result is `{"user_id":1,"step":1,"status":1}`.

My javabean is :

```
public class Login {
    private int user_id;
    private int status;
    private int step;

    public Login(int user_id, int status, int step) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.status = status;
        this.step = step;
    }
}
```

set...get...etc

When I use retrofit2:

```
instance = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.108/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

I get this

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

When I change the JavaBean to this:

```
public class Login {
    private String user_id;
    private String status;
    private String step;


}
```

I get the correct result. But I want a number, not string. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with Retrofit or JSON.

Resources$NotFoundException occurred when you tried to set the text to a `TextView`.

If an integer is supplied to the method `setText` of the `TextView`, it looks for string resource and crashes if not found.

So, you should first convert the `Integer` to `String` before setting it in a `TextView`.

Use something like this:

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(login.user_id));
```